# Understanding code in strlen implementation

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers, gcc

I have two questions regarding the implementation of `strlen` in `string.h` in glibc.

1. The implementation uses a magic number with 'holes'. I am not able to understand how this works. Can someone please help me understand this snippet:

   ```
   size_t
   strlen (const char *str)
   {
      const char *char_ptr;
      const unsigned long int *longword_ptr;
      unsigned long int longword, himagic, lomagic;

      /* Handle the first few characters by reading one character at a time.
         Do this until CHAR_PTR is aligned on a longword boundary.  */
      for (char_ptr = str; ((unsigned long int) char_ptr
                & (sizeof (longword) - 1)) != 0;
           ++char_ptr)
        if (*char_ptr == '\0')
          return char_ptr - str;

      /* All these elucidatory comments refer to 4-byte longwords,
         but the theory applies equally well to 8-byte longwords.  */

      longword_ptr = (unsigned long int *) char_ptr;

      /* Bits 31, 24, 16, and 8 of this number are zero.  Call these bits
         the "holes."  Note that there is a hole just to the left of
         each byte, with an extra at the end:

         bits:  01111110 11111110 11111110 11111111
         bytes: AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB CCCCCCCC DDDDDDDD

         The 1-bits make sure that carries propagate to the next 0-bit.
         The 0-bits provide holes for carries to fall into.  */

       himagic = 0x80808080L;
          lomagic = 0x01010101L;
          if (sizeof (longword) > 4)
          {
              /* 64-bit version of the magic.  */
              /* Do the shift in two steps to avoid a warning if long has 32 bits.  */
              himagic = ((himagic << 16) << 16) | himagic;
                lomagic = ((lomagic << 16) << 16) | lomagic;
            }
          if (sizeof (longword) > 8)
            abort ();

          /* Instead of the traditional loop which tests each character,
             we will test a longword at a time.  The tricky part is testing
             if *any of the four* bytes in the longword in question are zero.  */
          for (;;)
            {
              longword = *longword_ptr++;

              if (((longword - lomagic) & ~longword & himagic) != 0)
            {
              /* Which of the bytes was the zero?  If none of them were, it was
                 a misfire; continue the search.  */

              const char *cp = (const char *) (longword_ptr - 1);

              if (cp[0] == 0)
                return cp - str;
              if (cp[1] == 0)
                return cp - str + 1;
              if (cp[2] == 0)
                return cp - str + 2;
              if (cp[3] == 0)
                return cp - str + 3;
              if (sizeof (longword) > 4)
                {
                  if (cp[4] == 0)
                return cp - str + 4;
                  if (cp[5] == 0)
                return cp - str + 5;
                  if (cp[6] == 0)
                return cp - str + 6;
        if (cp[7] == 0)
         return cp - str + 7;
   }}}
   ```

   What is the magic number being used for?
2. Why not simply increment pointer until NULL character and return count? Is this approach faster? Why is it so?

Comment: On most architectures, glibc will use even faster functions. On modern Intel chips, for example, it uses SIMD extensions to vectorize the check.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is used to look at 4 bytes (32 bits) or even 8 (64 bits) in one go, to check if one of them is zero (end of string), instead of checking each byte individually.

Here is one example to check for a null byte:

```
unsigned int v; // 32-bit word to check if any 8-bit byte in it is 0
bool hasZeroByte = ~((((v & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | v) | 0x7F7F7F7F);
```

For some more see [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord).

The one used here (32-bit example):

> There is yet a faster method — use hasless(v, 1), which is defined
>   below; it works in 4 operations and requires no subsquent
>   verification. It simplifies to
>
> `#define haszero(v) (((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)`
>
> The subexpression (v - 0x01010101UL), evaluates to a high bit set in
>   any byte whenever the corresponding byte in v is zero or greater than
>   0x80. The sub-expression ~v & 0x80808080UL evaluates to high bits set
>   in bytes where the byte of v doesn't have its high bit set (so the
>   byte was less than 0x80). Finally, by ANDing these two sub-expressions
>   the result is the high bits set where the bytes in v were zero, since
>   the high bits set due to a value greater than 0x80 in the first
>   sub-expression are masked off by the second.

Looking at one byte at a time costs at least as much cpu cycles as looking at a full interger value (register wide). In this algorithm, full integers are checked to see if they contain a zero. If not, little instructions are used, and a *jump* can be made to the next full integer. If there is a zero byte inside, a further check is done to see at what exact position it was.

Comment: In addition, what the gcc `strlen` implementation does is optimize to take advantage of architectures where 8-byte integers are supported. Above you are limited to looking for a null in 4-bytes at a time. The `if (sizeof (longword) > 4)` comparison in `strlen` extends the comparison for an additional 4-bytes. The benefit either way is improved `strlen` performance for strings longer than approximately 32-chars. (above what you get with a *char-by-char check*). Good answer.